# CSS for specific table rows

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table with several rows. The top rows contains headings, while the rows under it have the id attribute of data. I have been trying to set CSS for the table rows that only have the id attribute data, but have so far only been able to set it for the entire table.

```
<table width = "80%" align="center" id="example">
<tr>
<td><h3>ID</h3></td>
<td><h3>First Name</h3></td>
<td><h3>Last Name</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr id="data">
<td>1</td>
<td>Joe</td>
<td>Schmoe## Heading ##</h3><td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS. I tried changing #example tr to tr #data with no luck. I know that I am overlooking something simple, but I am unsure what.

```
table#example {
    border-collapse: collapse;   
}
tr #data{
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
tr #data:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
tr #data {
    background-color: #fff;
}
tr #data th, tr #data td {
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
tr #data td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I'm not using classes because I'm not familiar enough with CSS and being able to use id only once is not a limitation for what I need.

Comment: `id`-s should be **unique**.. use a `class` instead

Comment: Just so you know, you shouldn't apply contradicting properties to one thing. You have in your CSS `tr #data {background-color: #eee;}` but then a couple down, you have `tr #data {background-color: #fff;}`

Comment: If you want to get familiar with css - watch this tutorial series (CSS/CSS3 tutorial from phpacademy.org): http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL860319852CD11A5C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a class, but better yet, don't use classes at all (HTML markup is your friend)! Here's a clean solution to your problem:

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Schmoe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  /* More styles here */
}

td {
  background: #EEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}

tr:hover td {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
}

/* Styles upon styles */
```

Simply use the [`th` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/th) to specify the *table header*. To get each table data row to highlight as you mouse over it, simply use the `tr:hover td` rule to catch that case. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNPEj/) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks, although this has the effect of making each td noticeably clickable, as opposed to each row. Is there a way to keep all but the top row noticeably clickable, instead of each cell?

Comment: I've added a fiddle and modified the style rules to work for the case you want.

Comment: Thanks very much. One last question, is it possible to have the entire row be a colour, instead of each td, so there is no white between the cells?

Comment: I believe that is possible. Just set the color on the `tr` element, instead of the `td`. However, I don't see any white between the cells in Firefox. Make sure you set `cellspacing='0'` on the `table` element in your HTML (it's an HTML attribute). You can also set `cellpadding='0'` if you like.